# Issue with focus in ie browser using selenium webdriver code

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Firstly i need to mouse over and then it opens a drop down then i will click on that link.Its working fine in firefox,chrome and issue is in ie.

Here is the code

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/span/form[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/span[3]/li/a"));

Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(element).build().perform();


WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/span/form[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/span[3]/li/ul/span[1]/li/a"));
Actions act1=new Actions(driver);
    //act1.click(element2);
act1.moveToElement(element2).click(element2).build().perform();
```

It works even in IE browser, when we use this piece of code

```
caps.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
```

If we use `requiredwindow` focus its working fine even in IE browser so no issues with locators

But am not encouraged to use above `requiredwindowfoucs` code in my project.
Is there any other way to do it.

The issue in Ie browser when we are not using `requiredwindowfocus`, it is clicking on some other link, so am assuming the problem is with focus.

so kindly help me with this issue without using `requiredfoucswindow`

Answer (score 0):

I have has similar issues in my project. In IE, clicking drop down values does not work. I have a pretty weird and unexpected solution for this. Find the element before performing the operations. I am assuming that this is required because when you move to element1 and when trying to find element the IE Xpath processor messes up the focus.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/span/form[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/span[3]/li/a"));

WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/span/form[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/span[3]/li/ul/span[1]/li/a"));

Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
act.moveToElement(element2).click(element2).build().perform();
```

Please try this and let me know if this works for you too!!

Also, consider using relative XPaths instead of the absolute XPaths you have used. The second Action is not required. One action should do the trick.

**EDIT Based on user comment**

Move to element1 is working and the list is getting displayed. So I am assuming that element2 is visible and so we can directly click on it without using the `Actions` class

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
element2.click();
```

Comment: Its moving towards that but unable to click on it.i mean link

Comment: It's it able to move to element1 and then to element2?

Comment: its moving towards first elemt1 and then it opens list i have to click on one of the element in list.Its not happenig